# Show Duplicate Items/id in different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I've made a query to check duplicate items and to display duplicate id's in different columns rather than different rows.

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(*), Max(id) AS dupes1, MIN(id) AS dupes2
FROM table
GROUP BY uid 
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Another Set of query

```
SELECT y.uid, x.id
FROM table x
JOIN (SELECT t.uid
      FROM table t
  GROUP BY t.uid
    HAVING COUNT(t.uid) > 1) y ON y.uid = x.uid
    where Len(y.uid) > 11
    order by y.uid
```

This works fine for 2 duplicate item's but I want to show all the duplicate items in different columns

**Expected Output**

`uid count dupes1 dupes2 dupes3 and so on...`

Comment: If there are 3 rows with same uid, what's the expected result? Add some sample table data, and the expected result,

Comment: result should be like:

id, count, dup1, dup2,dup3

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Then you need dynamic sql to do so

Comment: Please add some sample  data and result...

Comment: @sandeeprawat added

Comment: Strange things you want, Luke.

Comment: What if one record has hundreds of duplicates and another one only a few?

Comment: max item is i think is 10

Comment: Make 10 left joins then.

Comment: any code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(*), 
-- A varchar column to show all duplicates with the format 1,2,3
STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + CAST(id AS varchar(10)) FROM table b WHERE a.uid = b.uid FOR XML PATH ('')
), 1, 1, '') AS dupes
FROM table a
GROUP BY uid 
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: yes i want this kind of result but is it possible to get the dupes in different column rather than single column